# AKS with Azure Key Vault - env variables don't load

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

I'm trying to use secrets from Azure Key Vault in my Kubernetes deployment as env variables and I'm struggling to do so. I'm using Azure pod identity and the secrets get mounted to the file and that works, however I want them to be accessible as env variables.

Here is my secrets.yml file:

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: azure-kvname
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: test-secret
    type: Opaque
    data:
    - objectName: test-db-user
      key: dbuser
    - objectName: test-db-pass
      key: dbpassword
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "true"
    keyvaultName: "test-keyvault"      
    cloudName: ""               
    objects:  |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: test-db-user
          objectType: secret
          objectVersion: ""
        - |
          objectName: test-db-pass
          objectType: secret
          objectVersion: ""
    tenantId: "<tenantID>"
```

And my deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-secrets-store-inline
  labels:
    aadpodidbinding: aadpodidbinding
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets-store-inline
          mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
          readOnly: true
      env:
        - name: DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: test-secret
              key: dbuser
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: test-secret
              key: dbpassword
  volumes:
    - name: secrets-store-inline
      csi:
        driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
        readOnly: true
        volumeAttributes:
          secretProviderClass: azure-kvname
```

I've been following the examples provided by Azure: [secret](https://github.com/Azure/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/blob/master/examples/sync-as-kubernetes-secret/synck8s_v1alpha1_secretproviderclass.yaml), [deployment](https://github.com/Azure/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/blob/master/examples/sync-as-kubernetes-secret/deployment-synck8s.yaml)

When I apply both files, I get the `CreateContainerConfigError`: `Error: secret "test-secret" not found`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I did not have the proper RBAC roles enabled:

https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/troubleshooting/#failed-to-create-kubernetes-secret-errsecrets-is-forbidden-user-systemserviceaccountdefaultsecrets-store-csi-driver-cannot-create-resource-secrets-in-api-group--in-the-namespace-default

After adding them to my cluster, everything works perfectly.